# Find Avg of Top 30 Results

Tags: sql-server, average

I have a query to output top 30 results

```
select top 30 * from [dbo].[Stats]
        where Rack_Code = 'ABC'
        order by Date_of_Record desc
```

and query to get averages for all time

```
SELECT AVG(Total_MB - (East_MB + West_MB)) AS Other,
                    AVG(East_MB) AS East,
                    AVG(West_MB) AS West
                    FROM [dbo].[Stats]
                    WHERE Rack_Code = 'ABC'
```

Which give correct output

[image]

But when I try to get averages for Top 30 entries, the SQL query seems to ignore `Top 30`

```
SELECT TOP 30 AVG(Total_MB - (East_MB + West_MB)) AS Other,
                    AVG(East_MB) AS East,
                    AVG(West_MB) AS West
                    FROM [dbo].[Stats]
                    WHERE Rack_Code = 'ABC'
```

And gives incorrect output

[image]

Please advise

Comment: without a `GROUP BY`, you'll get a single row as an output

Comment: @ughai Yes, I wish to have single row as output

Comment: You don't have an order by in your final query, so top is kind of random.

Comment: are you looking for an average of only the top 30 rows based on `Date_of_Record`?

Comment: @ughai correct, I am looking for average for top 30 rows based on `Date_of_Record`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it, all you have to do is place your `TOP 30` inside sub-query or CTE and than do your `AVG`

```
SELECT AVG(Total_MB - ( East_MB + West_MB )) AS Other
   ,AVG(East_MB) AS East
   ,AVG(West_MB) AS West
FROM (
       SELECT TOP 30 *
        FROM [dbo].[stats]
        WHERE Rack_Code = 'ABC'
        ORDER BY Date_of_Record DESC
     ) a
```

Please note that the only time you can use `ORDER BY` in subquery is when you have `TOP` clause.

CTE solution,

```
;WITH   base
          AS (
               SELECT TOP 30 *
                FROM [dbo].[stats]
                WHERE Rack_Code = 'ABC'
                ORDER BY Date_of_Record DESC
             )
    SELECT AVG(Total_MB - ( East_MB + West_MB )) AS Other
           ,AVG(East_MB) AS East
           ,AVG(West_MB) AS West
        FROM base
```

[Documentataion](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) on CTE. Note that SQL-Server treats CTE as a view. This can introduce some overhead and if it nested deep enough then query optimizer is unable to read statistics and can create big performance drop.

Comment: @vladimir-oselsky CTE? Will research this.

Comment: @vladimir-oselsky Oh I remember Views from a while back, it froze my database!

Comment: Views in it selves are not bad. Bad code inside a view is where the problem arises. Especially if bad views reference other bad views. In that case selecting data from a view can kill whole server.